# MySQL procedure CALL multiple procedures

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, call

My question is pretty straight forward. **Is it possible to create a procedure that calls multiple previously stored procedures** such as:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE  `CALL_A_B_C` ( ) 
NOT DETERMINISTIC MODIFIES SQL DATA SQL SECURITY DEFINER  
CALL `A` ();
CALL `B`();
CALL `C`();
```

This code doesn't work but you get the idea. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer yes it is possible. Your code for an outer stored procedure might look like this

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_abc()
BEGIN
  CALL sp_a();
  CALL sp_b();
  CALL sp_c();
END$$
DELIMITER
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2616f/1)** demo

Comment: each call will be asynch or blocking?

Comment: @iBabur Sequential. There is no concept of async calls in MySQL or AFAIK any other major RDBMS for that matter