# How to run multiple MySQL stored procedures using docker exec

Tags: mysql, docker, stored-procedures

I'm trying to automate these steps that I'm doing manually:

```bash
# Go into the container
docker exec -it mysql-container sh

# Log into MySQL
mysql -u root -ptest

# Specify the database
USE mydatabase;

# Call procedure_1
CALL procedure_1();

# Call procedure_2
CALL procedure_2();
```

My first approach was:

```bash
docker exec mysql-container mysql -u root -ptest -e "USE mydatabase; CALL procedure_1(); CALL procedure_2();"
```

I got an error that said `procedure_1` doesn't exist. I looked around and found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20027137/5530965) so I updated my script to:

```bash
docker exec mysql-container mysql -u root -ptest -e "DELIMITER # USE mydatabase# BEGIN CALL procedure_1(); CALL procedure_2(); END# DELIMITER ;"
```

However this didn't seem to run at all, I didn't get any feedback. How do I call multiple MySQL stored procedures using `docker exec`?

Comment: Did you start the container with a published port?  If so, can you run `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 mydatabase` on the host, without using the `docker exec` debugging tool?

Comment: @DavidMaze port mapping is defined as `3307:3306`.

Comment: Did you create the procedure before calling it?

Comment: FWIW, it's not easy to use `DELIMITER` on the command-line, because it always interprets the rest of the current line as the delimiter string. Also you can't use `BEGIN` in MySQL except inside the body of stored routines.

Comment: So, `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3307 mydatabase`, without doing anything Docker-specific.

Comment: I would take the hint from the 1st error message! You need to create that stored procedure first!